# How can I get the latest Azure Gallery Template for Resource Group Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I use the **Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate** Azure PowerShell cmdlet to get the Azure resource group gallery templates for resource group deployment but it is not working until I upgraded my PowerShell to the latest version (**1.0.1**).

What is/are the alternative way(s) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate** cmdlet has been deprecated in the latest Azure PowerShell revision (1.0.1).

There are a few alternatives.

1. Using **Azure Quickstart Templates**

   You can go to [Azure Quickstart Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/).

   This link consists of a list of the latest Azure gallery templates for quick start deployment which are always up-to-date.
2. GET request REST API call to Microsoft Azure Gallery endpoint

   Issue a GET request to the Microsoft Azure Gallery endpoint: https://gallery.azure.com/Microsoft.Gallery/GalleryItems?api-version=2015-10-01

   The expected response should be in JSON format consist of a list of Azure gallery template items.

   Below shows one of the gallery template returned from the JSON response.

> ```
> "identity": "Microsoft.Windows10Enterprisex64.1.0.0",
> "publisher": "Microsoft",
> "publisherDisplayName": "Microsoft",
> "itemName": "Windows10Enterprisex64",
> "itemDisplayName": "Windows 10 Enterprise (x64)",...
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much @juvchan! This is what I am looking for.